# Displaying regions from a list in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, array, panel, dropdownlist

I have generated a list with States of India but getting the following error while trying to display a region on the map.

```
Line 11: centerObject() requires a Geometry or Element. Got: Karnataka
```

'Karnataka' is the State which I tried to display.

Code used is as follows :

```
// Let's add a dropdown with the location names using aggregate_array()
var items = India.aggregate_array('NAME_1');
items.evaluate(function(List) {
  dropdown.items().reset(List),
  dropdown.setPlaceholder('Select Location');
});
var dropdown =ui.Select({
  placeholder: 'please wait...',
  onChange : function(key){
    Map.clear();
    Map.centerObject(key,7);
    Map.addLayer(key,{},dropdown.getValue());
  }
});

//Main Panel
var panel = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [dropdown],
  style: {backgroundColor: 'white'},
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('vertical')
});

//displaying the main panel
ui.root.insert(1,panel);
```

where 'India' is the imported asset and 'NAME_1' is the column with the names of various States.

How can I display the selected State on the map ? I believe the error is in Map.centerObject and Map.addLayer lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onChange function gets a string when the value changes (you've called that value 'key').  You need to use that string to filter your collection instead of just trying to display the string.  Your code isn't complete, but assuming that `India` is a FeatureCollection from something like a shapefile:

```
var dropdown = ui.Select({
  placeholder: 'please wait...',
  onChange : function(key){
    var region = India.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME1', key))
    Map.layers().reset()
    Map.centerObject(region,7);
    Map.addLayer(region,{},key);
  }
});
```

Comment: The code worked perfectly. `India` is the shapefile I'm using in which `NAME_1` represent the States and `NAME_2` represent Districts. Is it possible to create a new dropdown list based on the State I select ? For example, if I selected `KARNATAKA` as the State from the first dropdown list, the second dropdown list should display the list of Districts within the State of Karnataka. Strings in the second dropdown list must change based on the selection made to the first. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, just filter the collection the same way and do the same thing to fill in a second list, all inside the onChange function for the first dropdown.